# Seeing enum schema as object (and NOT as string)

Tags: java, enums, swagger-2.0

We have an Enum defined with Jackson annotation, "@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)"

e.g.

```
package com.test;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
@JsonFormat(shape =  JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum SampleEnumName {
    OPTION_1 ("NAME_1", "DESCRIPTION_1",  "CATEGORY_1"),
    OPTION_2 ("NAME_2", "DESCRIPTION_2",  "CATEGORY_2"),
    OPTION_3 ("NAME_3", "DESCRIPTION_3",  "CATEGORY_3");

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String category;

    private SampleEnumName(String name, String description, String category) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
}
```

When its schema is generated we see it as an object, e.g.

```
{"type":"object","id":"urn:jsonschema:com:test:SampleEnumName","properties":{"name":{"type":"string"},"description":{"type":"string"},"category":{"type":"string"}}}
```

But for the same, when we check the JSON generated by swagger, the following is shown in schema:

```
{"type":"string","enum":["OPTION_1","OPTION_2","OPTION_3"]}
```

Is there a way (some swagger annotation equivalent of Jackson annotation "@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)"), which can show Object definition of Enum?

We are using swagger 1.5.7

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem, updated to Swagger 2.9.2 and solved.